# How to redirect user to Home Page when they try to access folders in my root directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am a NOOB at PHP and Apache, In fact I just bought my first domain today, and I was wondering if it is at all possible to redirect a user to my home page when they attempt to access folders that I have in my root directory, but don't want them to see. I don't know the proper terminology, so please excuse me if I make a mistake. I am aware that it is possible to put a PHP file into the certain folders that you don't want people to access through the Apache Server, but I have no idea how to go about this.

For Example:

I have a folder within my Root directory named "images", with it's file path being "public_html/images". When you type in that url, "domainname.com/images", a page comes up that shows the user every file within that folder, and lets them view it with the help of Apache Server. My question is is it possible to put a php file within that folder that redirects the user to my homepage, and if so, can someone please describe/show me how to do so? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't want people to access files / directories don't put them in your document root period.

Comment: Also disable directory listings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the directories that you don't want people to be able to access simply drop an index.php file with the following:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://YOURURL.com");
exit;
?>
```

That should take care of it for you!

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much! That does exactly what I want it to do now! Such a simple code, but so challenging to me. Thanks again! I will accept this answer for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Nonono :)

Just put in .htaccess following string.
It will just disable list view all itmes in folder, will show 403 error on index, but correctly display all images.

`Options -Indexes`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/(.+) ../index.php [L,R]
```

Add this to your .htaccess in your images folder